# Split DF string column and add it as new column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take a DF column and build new column based on str splitting.
Column values looks like that: 
*abcd <> 1234*

In order to split i'm using the following:

```
df['user_id'] = df['Customer User Id'].str.split('<>').str.get(1)
```

This action works but i'm getting red window saying:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tried to replace the code with `loc`:

```
df['user_id'] = df.loc[:,['Customer User Id']]['Customer User Id'].str.split('<>|<').str.get(1)
```

but the error still shows

Any suggestions..

Comment: can you show what is your data? so that we can help you

Comment: Is `df` already a slice of another *DataFrame*? Either way, it is only a warning.

Comment: @pacholik Yes, df is already slice from raw_df

Comment: @RohanAmrute Not sure what data you want to see, the data in this column is strings looks like "abcd <> 1234" and i want to create new column with only the numbers on the right side

Comment: I tried  your code, there is no error or warning of such kind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with this Pandas warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-this-pandas-warning)

Comment: Take look at http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/1028589 .

Comment: Added screenshot with the message [link](https://goo.gl/XoSJNl)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this kind of data:

```
key1  key2  
22    abcd <> 1234  
34    abcd <> 1234  
12    abcd <> 1234  
55    abcd <> 1234
```

And the code is:

```
my_df["key3"] = my_df['key2'].str.split('<>').str.get(1)
```

Output is :

```
key1    key2    key3
22  abcd <> 1234    1234
34  abcd <> 1234    1234
12  abcd <> 1234    1234
55  abcd <> 1234    1234
```